# How to add proper spacing in my PSV file?

Tags: r, python-3.x, unix, kdb

I have a psv file for some config for my program and it looks really bad. When I save this config from kdb it removes all the white space and it looks like this:

```
column1|column2|column3
somevalue1|somevalue2|somevalue3
somevalue4|somevalue5|somevalue6
```

and I want it to look like this when I open it with a text editor like notepad or visual studio code

```
column1    |column2    |column3
somevalue1 |somevalue2 |somevalue3
somevalue4 |somevalue5 |somevalue6
```

This psv file has 20000 rows so please don't tell me I have to do this manually.

The reason for which I need to do this spacing is because sometimes my colleagues need to open it to modify just one thing and it is much more readable with the spacing.

I work on linux and I know kdb,python and R so anything in those languages that could help me?

Comment: An alternative could be to use an extension in your editor e.g. for VS Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv which adds an "align" button to bottom bar when editing delimited files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite crude but this q function will take an existing psv file and pad it out:

```
pad:{m:max each count@''a:flip"|"vs/:read0 x;x 0:"|"sv/:flip m$a}
```

It works by taking the max string length of each column and padding the rest of the values to the same width using `$`. The columns are then stitched back together and saved.

Taking this example file contents:

```
column1|column2|column3
somevalue1|somevalue2|somevalue3
somevalue4|somevalue5|somevalue6
somevalue7|somevalue8|somevalue9
```

Passing through pad in an open q session:

```
pad `:sample.psv
```

Gives the result:

```
column1   |column2   |column3
somevalue1|somevalue2|somevalue3
somevalue4|somevalue5|somevalue6
somevalue7|somevalue8|somevalue9
```

Comment: love it . I wrote something as well which is a lot longer than this one but a little bit more user friendly. I'll post my solution here as well if I have a bit of time to format it properly